# Why isn't the exponential part of fourier transform included while differentiating the fourier transform of f(x)?

Tags: fourier-transform

One of my friends asked this question. Initially, I also thought that it was obvious to take the derivative of only the function but now I am starting to have doubt about it.

Consider $F(K)$ is the Fourier transform of $f(x)$.

$$F(k)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)e^{ikx}\mathrm{d}x$$

so while taking derivative of its first order

$$F'(k)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f'(x)e^{ikx}dx $$

But why isn't the $e^{ikx}$ also not differentiated since $x$ is present there? Why isn't the chain rule applied to it? I hope this doesn't sound insane.

Thank you.

Comment: It does, unfortunately. Your formula for $F'(k)$ is definitely wrong.

Comment: Could you please give the correct answer for it?

Answer (score 2):

In the formula
$$F(\omega):={1\over\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\>e^{-i\omega x}\>dx$$
the variable $\omega$ acts as a parameter in the integral on the RHS. Differentiating under the integral sign with respect to this parameter (and neglecting questions of convergence etc.) gives 
$$F'(\omega):={1\over\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty (-ix) f(x)\>e^{-i\omega x}\>dx\ .$$

Comment: isn't this obtained after applying integration by parts?

Comment: Look at the third displayed formula here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: F(k)=$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{ikx}dx$=


F'(k)=$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f'(x)e^{ikx}dx$


Integration by parts


F'(k)=$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty (-ik)e^{ikx}f(x)dx$=

-$\frac{(ik)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ikx}f(x)dx$=

$-ikF(k)$


This is what i mean.

Comment: Sorry i still don't understand. I understand your answer but I don't understand what you meant for leibniz integral in that link.

Comment: Your idea how $F'(\omega)$ should be computed is dead wrong.